# PhoneGap Text to Speech (CrossPlatform) plugin

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform, phonegap-plugins, text-to-speech

I would like to make my PhoneGap (crossplatform IOS/Android) app talk when needed.

I found some TTS plugin - https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/863

But from the documentations It's not quite understandable how to connect and use it.

I unziped the plugin to plugins/ folder and added this line to config.xml file -

```
<plugin name="org.tt.plugin.tts" spec="1" source="pgb" />
```

And not sure what's next.